# How to match two different columns in two different tables having auto increment id primary key column?

Tags: sql, database-design

I need to match two columns in two different tables with auto incrementing primary key id columns. in one table user is recording ***book's title*** and in another table, user must input that the very ***book's author*** in the end I need to match book's title for author, but data keeps growing by users by inputting data. so how can I match these data

Comment: Please show your own attemp to do this.

Comment: Seems like you need a junction table to join authors with books.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc yeah but I thought but since both of the tables have auto-incrementing id columns, It seemed it doesn't work.

Comment: The junction table consists of another auto-incrementing id column, the book id, and the author id.  You create a unique index on (book id, author id).  You can also create a unique index on (author id, book id).  That's a textbook junction table.